# Planning to convert PDF to JPG, Annotate the image, Reconvert to PDF

Tags: php, programming-practices, jquery, imagemagick

I have a feature where scanned exam answer books need to be digitally annotated and marked.

The scanning portion of the work is with another vendor who refuses to scan in any format other than PDF as it's more secure and unalterable.

I need to develop code that can show the 20-odd pages in the PDF on screen using a web browser, annotate it with little ✓ and ✗ symbols, add marks, write comment, draw lines, etc. and save the PDF with this.

My current approach:

1. Use ImageMagick to extract individual pages from PDF as images
2. Load images with `<img>` tag in the browser
3. Use jQuery to create a context menu to make annotations
4. Save the left, top, width, height, text of the `<div>` element in a database in relation to each image of the PDF

Whenever someone requests an annotated PDF, I plan to serve it by once again extracting the PDF into images, retrieving and replacing the `<div>` elements back in the right place, and using FPDF to generate the PDF.

I have already done all this, and it's working fine.

I wonder if this is the right way to do it though? Seems a little backward, but I really can't think of any other way.

Please help to validate the method or suggest something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, see it this way: your input scan is already a raster image (the fact those raster grafics are in embedded in PDF is mostly irrelevant), so a raster image based process is all you can expect. Utilizing OCR might be an option, but it would probably only complicate the process with no real benefit and an additional source of potential errors.

If you want to improve the process, you need to start a step earlier: the exam answer books could be electronic PDF or HTML forms right from the start, with form fields for the answers and the annotations. Then you could shorten the whole annotation process and make the implementation much simpler. But I understand that for many real world cases, this kind of approach is not feasible: for example,  exams must be done handwritten on paper for legal reasons, or because having a fully electronic survey infrastructure is out of question. If yours belongs to this category, I think your solution sounds fully reasonable.

Comment: You're right. The exam papers have to be handwritten. Also, there will be possible graphs, figures, etc which can't be OCR-ed any case.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Acrobat (and other PDF software, as well) has many annotation features. The one that I would recommend is the "rubber stamp". You could have a red X and a green check mark defined as stamps, as an example. You can then plop them down on the PDF image where you want and then re-save the PDF.

Comment: Annotations is only one aspect of the solution I need to develop. There will be marks entry too, and the marks need to go to a database. This also needs to be a web based solution. Additionally, there is the issue of licensing Acrobat as this system needs to be simultaneously used by hundreds of evaluators.

Answer (score 0):

You can create annotated PDF using one of the free APIs, given you already have text, images and their locations on pages

Spire PDF would be one of these examples.